# How to set a Kubernetes Node's name in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm not having any luck in changing the name of a worker node in AWS EKS. I have not been able to find any documentation regarding how the node is named by default.

Currently my nodes are named as follows, for example

```
NAME                                           STATUS   ROLES            AGE     VERSION
ip-10-241-111-216.us-west-2.compute.internal   Ready                     44m     v1.14.7-eks-1861c5
```

I've tried passing in `--hostname-override` through the user data but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known limitation in AWS EKS in-tree cloud provider. It's discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54482) and it's still open.

Edit:- The AWS Out-of-tree cloud provider behaviour is documented [here](https://cloud-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io/prerequisites/)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.